# What is the header value used in NavigationPreloadManager for?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

**Question**
I've read the docs below but couldn't find the reason for using the "setHeaderValue" function?

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
  return registration.navigationPreload.setHeaderValue(newValue);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

**Reference**

1. [ServiceWorker Document in W3C](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#dom-navigationpreloadmanager-setheadervalue)
2. [NavigationPreloadManager Document in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigationPreloadManager)
3. [Navigation Preload Example](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/navigation+Preload+example+workbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're already familiar with service worker navigation preloads.

To allow servers to differentiate between regular requests and navigation preload requests, browsers use the `Service-Worker-Navigation-Preload` header.
By default, the value of this header is `true`, and `setHeaderValue(value)` allows you to override `true` with something else.
[This article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload#changing_the_header) explains it in more detail.

Comment: Is "setHeaderValue(value)" using to prevent it from pulling data from cache? Is "newValue" an ever-changing value in the article? What does the ID of the last post mean?

Comment: It can be used to implement your own server-side logic. You can set it to whatever you want, so the server can deal with it accordingly. The example in the article mentions using it for custom logic involving blog posts (where each blog post has an ID).
You shouldn't have to worry about it unless you want your server to handle navigation preload requests differently than regular requests.